# Reactjs: How do I remove the page-not-found component from every existing URL?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am building react app.
If a user types the wrong URL, the `NoMatch` component is shown (which is fine).

**Challenge** is that when a user types an existing URL, two components are shown. The `NoMatch` component and the expected component both appear.

Note: I found some questions about this on *stackoverflow*, but non of the solutions worked for me. I am using a `<PrivateRoute>` and `react-router-dom`.

App.js

```js
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
            <Fragment>
                <Navigationbar/>
                <div className="main-part">
                    <Sidebar/>
                    <main className="content shrunk-sidebar">
                        <PrivateRoute path="/" exact component={Home}/>
                        <PrivateRoute path="/files" exact component={Files}/>
                        <PrivateRoute path="/new_app" exact component={NewApp}/>
                        <PrivateRoute path="/applications/:app_name" exact component={Application} />
                        <PrivateRoute path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
                    </main>
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
</Provider>
```

PrivateRoute.js

```js
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, auth, ...rest}) => (
    <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
            auth.isAuthenticated ? (
                <Component {...props} />
            ) : (
                <Redirect
                    to={{
                        pathname: "/login",
                        state: {from: props.location}
                    }}
                />
            )
        }
    />
);
```

**That is the problem that I have.** 
[image]

Any idea what I am doing wrong that I do not get the result that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Switch` only works for it's direct children, when you add something like a `Fragment` inside it, Switch loses it's effect on the `Route` components inside it.

In your case, you can simply move the `Switch` inside to contain the array of `PrivateRoute` components to make it work

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
            <Fragment>
                <Navigationbar/>
                <div className="main-part">
                    <Sidebar/>
                    <main className="content shrunk-sidebar">
                        <Switch>
                            <PrivateRoute path="/" exact component={Home}/>
                            <PrivateRoute path="/files" exact component={Files}/>
                            <PrivateRoute path="/new_app" exact component={NewApp}/>
                            <PrivateRoute path="/applications/:app_name" exact component={Application}/>
                            <PrivateRoute path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
                        </Switch>
                    </main>
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
</Provider>
```

Comment: I slightly modified your answer so that the code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add a wrapping component for the "correct" paths, that has a check that if the pathname is one of the correct paths, you render its children, otherwise render  component. Quick example:

```
<WrappingComponent>
  <Route component={Home} exact path='/' />
  <Route component={SomePage} path='/some-page' />
</WrappingComponent>
```

Then in the wrapping component pathname check:

```
  if (this.props.location.pathname === '/' ||
    this.props.location.pathname === '/some-page') {
      return this.props.children;
  } else {
    return <NoMatch />;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove path from it

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
            <Fragment>
                <Navigationbar/>
                <div className="main-part">
                    <Sidebar/>
                    <main className="content shrunk-sidebar">
                        <PrivateRoute path="/" exact component={Home}/>
                        <PrivateRoute path="/files" exact component={Files}/>
                        <PrivateRoute path="/new_app" exact component={NewApp}/>
                        <PrivateRoute path="/applications/:app_name" exact component={Application} />
                        <PrivateRoute  component={NoMatch}/>
                    </main>
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
</Provider>
```